# C# AJAX Comments in post

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

Here I made a simple webpage to post pictures, text, etc. I also made a simple ajax file to send the text, picture, etc to the database, and retrieve that information to be displayed in the same webpage. Here is the main webpage:

```
<div class="here" id="here">
@foreach (var photo in db.Query(photos, galleryInfo)){
 <div class="com_1 com_3">
   <div class="com_4">
     <div class="com_44">
       <img alt="miniatura" style="margin-top: 0" src="@Href("~/Photo/Thumbnail2", photo.UserId, new { size="small" })" class="thumbnail-border thumb22" />
        <div class="n-s">
          <b>@photo.Nombre @photo.Apellido</b>
        </div>
     </div>
  <div class="com_5">
    @photo.Comment
  </div>       
</div>
  <div class="comcom">
    <div class="comcom1">
       <form onsubmit="return fofon(this)" id="gog">
         <input type="text" style="display: none" name="GroupId" value="@galleryInfo" />
         <textarea  class="texta"name="comment" placeholder="Write a comment..."></textarea>
         <input type="submit" class="g_sub"/>
       </form>
    </div>
  </div>         
</div>
}
```

In case it gets confuse, this shows every post with a "comment section" below each one (we can call them "Commne2"). The ajax will get the text, picture etc, send it to the database, and post it to another file, which will be displayed here... in the @foreach{}.
Obviously, the posts do not "excist", so any javascript that affects that post, will not work, because that element does not exciste in this case.
So my problem is, how can I create an ajax file (javascript file) that affects the Comment2 so that I can comment a post?

Comment: It is not clear exactly where you are having difficulty. Can you please post what you have tried in JavaScript and show where you are having difficulty.

Comment: The problem that I have in genearal, is that I don´t know how to make a javascript code affect an element that has been send via ajax, because that element or elements do not tecnically excist